# How to make Compass/Sass compilation command generate parsable output

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass

I’d like to automate the compilation of Compass projects and be able to get output that I can parse so I can take only what I need (the errors) and further format them how I want.

The issue is that Compass output is not in a format that can be easily parsed (it has error messages on multiple lines).

Is there any reliable way to parse this output? Or… any idea what would need to be changed and where in [Compass’s code](https://github.com/Compass/compass) to allow a new param that would allow you to specify the output format (e.g. JSON, XML)?

I’m asking this because I don’t know Ruby, so I would need a starting point. Their current code is not easy to understand (due to the fact that I don’t know Ruby), but if I at least have a starting point I would try to see what I can do and hopefully create a pull request with this if I get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I think, there is another way to solve this problem, what you think about to parse the output css and do not touch compass.

There is a good framework for creating postproccesor for css:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss

You can do what you want with output css and send message to console or send email or other things, and many other things.